# Seeking opinions on some Architecture decisions for a Web front End Ext JS based

Tags: perl, extjs

I have started work on a little programming project basically a web based invoicing program . I will want it to be usable from smart phones. 
  I have decided on the back end which is Perl - Dancer- Moose - Kiokudb which I'm pretty happy with for now (Yes I know there are some  around already).

I am now trying to make a choice over the presentation layer for the project.  Initially I thought the traditional html template, page per function type arrangement.  Last night I started looking at Ext Js/Sencha.  This does look pretty neat and I can see how it could make a pretty good front end to something like an invoicing app.  What I would like some thoughts on is what is  the ideal way to handle the  generation of the forms.
  As I see it I have a couple of options with Ext Js (or Dojo or any of these sort of frameworks)
1.  I could code each form directly into a Javascript file this seems to be the route most of the demo's take.  But it seems awkward to me to code a html form in Javascript when I could just write it in HTML?  Am I missing something?

1. I could dynamically generate the forms from the data,  This means I would need to store meta-data linked to the data which I could do in Moose using traits.  But then how do you deal with things like order of display with out getting messy?  What's your thoughts on storing display meta-data with the data object?
2. I could still generate the forms using html templates and use Ext Js to enhance these,  this doesn't seem to be encouraged by Ext Js though it is possible.

One thing I will say having all the display work done in Javascript does present the opportunity to completely separate the presentation layer from the rest of the code.

Any opinions on what you think is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written several large web-apps with the presentation layer based on Ext Js (all of them use ASP.Net server-side).  My first app was written as traditional HTML and enhanced with Ext Js on the client.  The theory here was that some end-users may take advantage of the option to execute without JavaScript.  In reality, this never happened.  Granted, this was not an Amazon.com-style website.

The next couple of apps pretty much abandoned HTML.  We had some concerns about embracing a "non-standard" presentation layer.  But, it's so simple to design an Ext layout.  We found that non-programmers could look at an Ext layout (it's just a JavaScript object) and understand most everything.  It's also easy to load new JavaScript files dynamically; so we could grow the apps naturally.

Currently, we have a handful of traditional ASP.Net pages (for login, fatal errors, etc), and a controller layer in C#.  Only one ASP.Net page is needed for the conduit from JS to C#.  The rest of the presentation layer is done in Ext Js.  We actually leveraged this design to create an off-line app of one of our apps.  To do this, we only had to replace the handful of ASP.Net pages (we could reuse 100% of the Ext Js code and 100% of the C# code).

We talked about generating forms using meta-data, but decided against it.  We decided that maintaining the meta-data and various generators could become a larger job than just writing code by hand.

Comment: That's great Harley, the sort of answer I was hoping for, one based on experience. Your approach really does to seem to give a really clean break between front and back end. I appreaciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Ext extensively, but I have build a framework for dynamic application with [POE::XUL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE-XUL/).  All forms are generated from a series of YAML config files, which also contains metadata about how a given element interfaces with the backend.  And while I did not make the full power of XUL available to the form designers, this can be seen as a Good Thing.

At the time, I thought that requiring Firefox or xulrunner for an intranet app would be acceptable.  It turns out that PHBs really like their MSIE.  However, Ext wasn't really an option when I started writing the framework.

Some point soon I hope to refactor the framework so that it will work with all browsers, most likely using Ext Js in the browser.  As my target is intranet applications, saying "you must have JS enabled" is acceptable.

And by having my forms defined in YAML, I will be able to move all the applications that have been written for the XUL-only framework to the Ext framework and they should Just Work.

However writing a metadata-driven framework is a more advanced problem.  You didn't specify your skill level.  If you are only beginner, I'd suggest pure-Ext in the browser talking cometd to the backend.

Comment: Thanks Leolo,  I have considered having the meta data in a third repository mainly so I could use it for the front end and back end. As as example I could use the YAML config to verify data at the backend (though Moose negates this need to a degree).  Thinking about it though if I was to implement it from scratch maybe I should store it in  JSON format that Ext can use directly, I could still in theory parse into Perl objects for use in the backend.

Comment: Yeah JSON would be a good idea.  However, JSON might be easier for the designers to mess up, compared to YAML.  I find you need "such-and-such error on line XX of file foo.yml" for them to figure stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's a done thing to add another option, but [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/index.html) allows you to build forms in HTML, then turn them into dijit (dojo widgets) one in the browser.